# How to include FontAwesome Icon in a React.js project

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to display a glyphicon using the following package, https://github.com/danawoodman/react-fontawesome.  I read through the documentation on the Github page but am having trouble connecting the dots.  I understand that I need to import the FontAwesome library in the appropriate file that I would like to see the glyphicon appear in.

**App.js**

```
    import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
    import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

                {/* insert icon below */}

                {/* React.render(<FontAwesome name='rocket' />, document.body);*/}

                {/* className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" */}
```

I have tried the following solutions, but neither of them work.  Any help on how I can get a glyphicon to display would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an easy fix.  I needed to include the FontAwesome CDN to the project.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Cool!! Thanks :)